# Symfony2 getId non-object error

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

Hy everybody, i've got a problem with my Bundle when I'm trying to obtain the ID of an user.

```
$user = $userManager->findUserById($tmpID['uid']);
```

Where **$tmpID['uid']** is the ID of the user and when I'm trying to to $user->getId() I obtain an error.

This is the error

```
FatalErrorException: Error: Call to a member function getId() on a non-object in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Api/src/Api/ApiBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php line 263
```

MyBundle\Entity\User.php

```
<?php

namespace MyBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User as BaseUser;

 /**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 */

class User extends BaseUser
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 *
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="text", nullable=true)
 */
protected $description;


/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="genre", type="integer", nullable=false)
 */
protected $genre;


/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="device", type="string", nullable=true)
 */
protected $device;


/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="avatar", type="string", nullable=true)
 */
protected $avatar;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="phone", type="integer", nullable=true)
 */
protected $phone;

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    // your own logic
}

public function getDescription() {
    return $this->description;
}

public function setDescription($description) {
    $this->description = $description;
}

public function getGenre() {
    return $this->genre;
}

public function setGenre($genre) {
    $this->genre = $genre;
}

public function getDevice() {
    return $this->device;
}

public function setDevice($device) {
    $this->device = $device;
}


public function getPhone() {
    return $this->phone;
}

public function setPhone($phone) {
    $this->phone = $phone;
}

public function getAvatar() {
    return $this->avatar;
}

public function setAvatar($avatar) {
    $this->avatar = $avatar;
}

}
```

Comment: If you var_dump the `$user` does it show a proper user object with ID? Could you provide the code for `findUserById()`? Furthermore there is no getter for `$id` in your entity

Comment: This error means that the $user was not actually loaded.  Try doing a dump of $tmpID to confirm that the array has the userID.

Comment: Using **var_dum()** I get **NULL**. 
Then, how @George says, $user isn't loaded, but how?...
Here's the 'findUserById'
    `}

    /**
     * Find a user by ID
     *
     * param string $id
     * return UserInterface
     *
     */

    public function findUserById($id)
    {
        return $this->findUserBy(array('id' => $id));
    }`

Comment: @JorgeBrage The **NULL** means it cannot find user by the ID, maybe your custom `findBy` is not correct; or maybe the the type of id should be integer or object not string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While i was going to the office **I get the solution**! :)

On my function `$tmpID`is an variable wich has the token of an user when that used login into Symfony. The problem it was I was using a token of an user wich didn't exist into the DDBB (Yes, i erased the user 5 minutes before to get that error)

Then, i was trying to obtain a non-existent user and that's the reason why i get `NULL` for `$user`

I hope my problem can help other people.

p.s. Thanks to @Javad and @George for the suggestions